# extract string by regular expressions in c#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have some html files with codes like this :

```
 <div style="border: 0px red solid; width: 633px; position: relative; margin: 0px;
                                                                float: right">
                                                                <font style="font-size: 8pt; color: Navy; font-weight: Bold;">Unit Name: </font>My Unit Name&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <font style="font-size: 8pt; color: Navy; font-weight: Bold;">
                                                                    Manager: </font>My Manager Name&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <font style="font-size: 8pt;
                                                                        color: Navy; font-weight: Bold;">Category: </font>My Category
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div style="border: 0px red solid; width: 122px; position: relative; margin: 0px;
                                                                padding: 0px;">
                                                                <button name="sSdewfwo87kjLKH7624QAZMLLPIdyt75576rtffTfdef22de" style="font-family: Tahoma;"
                                                                    onclick="OpenMyWin2(1,843442,8445,'bf61fd588f00cbe7a37dab20c62e1c63')">
                                                                    More Info</button></div>
```

I want to extract info in front of Category: & Manager: & Unit Name:. How can I use RegularExpression to extract those from large html file. those files may have 100 similar items.

Comment: The best way to handle this kind of tasks is through a dedicated library like [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex is a no-no. For a laugh, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you consider using that tool:
http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

It allows easily parse any HTML you want.

Answer (score 0):

It is a **bad idea to use regex to parse HTML** code, however if you want to use regex anyway, use pattern:

```
>\s*Unit Name:[^>]*>([^<]+).*?>\s*Manager:[^>]*>([^<]+).*?>\s*Category:[^>]*>([^<]+)
```

which can be reduced to

```
>\s*(?:Unit Name|Manager|Category):[^>]*>([^<]+)
```

---

To trim `&nbsp;` tails replace `([^<]+)` in the regex pattern with `(\w+)`.

Comment: I have a HTML string that repeat my pattern for 50 times in every page. I use IndexOf with an index. I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you. This uses **[Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Width Assertions.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**

```
 (?<=(Category:|Manager:|Unit Name:) (</font>)?).*?(?=(&|<))
```

RegexBuddy ScreenShot

[image]